How to use Cicerone guides in a shiny app with multiple tabs and multiple modules?
I've looked at the documentation for how to use Cicerone with modules, and how to use it with tabs.  However in my case of combining the two for a more complex app with nested tabs and nested modules, I've been unable to create a guide that tours through multiple tabs.
When I switch to the second tab that is part of the tour first, and then run the tour, it works, so my element is correct, but somehow it isn't switching to the tab on it's on to put the element in context. (Note that that functionality isn't included here)
Is it possible that when I am on the first tab, the element in the second tab hasn't been created yet?  If so, I don't know how the tab and tab_id arguments would ever work, unless it's due to the hierarchical nature of my modules and tabs.
Here is a simplified example app:
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(cicerone)



# Module for subtabs ------------------------------------------------------

mod_subtabs_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = ns("subTabs"),
      tabPanel("Chart", mod_chart_ui(ns("chart_1"))),
      tabPanel("Table", mod_table_ui(ns("table_1")))
    )
  )
}

mod_subtabs_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    mod_chart_server("chart_1")
    mod_table_server("table_1")
  })
}


# Module for chart --------------------------------------------------------

mod_chart_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
      plotOutput(ns("chart"))
  )
}

mod_chart_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    output$chart <- renderPlot(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_point())

  })
}


# Module for table --------------------------------------------------------

mod_table_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        mod_filter_ui(ns("filter_chart"))),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput(ns("table"))
      )
    )
  )
}

mod_table_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    filt_mtcars <- isolate(mod_filter_server("filter_chart"))

    output$table <- renderTable(filt_mtcars())

  })
}


# Module for filter -------------------------------------------------------

mod_filter_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
      selectInput(ns("cyl_filt"),
                  label = "Filter for # of Cylinders",
                  choices = NULL)
    )
}

mod_filter_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    updateSelectInput("cyl_filt",
                      session = session,
                      choices = unique(mtcars$cyl),
                      selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)[1])

    filt_mtcars <- reactive(mtcars |> filter(cyl == input$cyl_filt))

    return(filt_mtcars)


  })
}



# Cicerone ----------------------------------------------------------------

guide <- Cicerone$
  new()$
  step(el = "mainTabs",
       "Main Tabs",
       "These are the main tabs set in the main server")$
  step(el = "tab1-subTabs",
       "Sub Tabs",
       "These are the subtabs under Tab1")$
  step(el = "tab1-chart_1-chart",
       "Chart",
       "This is a chart!")$
  step(el = "tab1-table_1-table", #This step does not work
       "Table",
       "This is a table!",
       tab = "table_1",
       tab_id = "tab1-table_1")$
  step(el = "tab1-table_1-table-cyl_filt", #This step does not work
       "Filters",
       "Here you can filter the table by number of cylinders.")




# Main app ----------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  use_cicerone(),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id = "mainTabs",
      tabPanel("tab1", mod_subtabs_ui("tab1")),
      tabPanel("tab2", mod_subtabs_ui("tab2"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  guide$init()$start()
  
  mod_subtabs_server("tab1")
  mod_subtabs_server("tab2")


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)



Concerning: #65: Are you using the latest CRAN version (1.0.4)? Tabs are not working there. If you install the development version from github it should work: remotes::install_github("JohnCoene/cicerone") (cicerone_1.0.5.9000).


Is it possible that when I am on the first tab, the element in the
second tab hasn't been created yet? If so, I don't know how the tab
and tab_id arguments would ever work, unless it's due to the
hierarchical nature of my modules and tabs.

Yes, I made three main changes which should make it work using the current development version of cicerone (1.0.5.9000).

Your tab and tab_id in the fourth step have to be changed to
tab = "Table",
tab_id = "tab1-subTabs"


The table needs suspendWhenHidden = FALSE:
outputOptions(output, "tab1-table_1-table", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)


I select the selectInput on the second tab by class because in your app it does not have an id:
el = ".form-group.shiny-input-container"




library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(cicerone)
#packageVersion("cicerone")
#[1] ‘1.0.5.9000’

# Module for subtabs ------------------------------------------------------

mod_subtabs_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = ns("subTabs"),
      tabPanel("Chart", mod_chart_ui(ns("chart_1"))),
      tabPanel("Table", mod_table_ui(ns("table_1")))
    )
  )
}

mod_subtabs_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    mod_chart_server("chart_1")
    mod_table_server("table_1")
  })
}


# Module for chart --------------------------------------------------------

mod_chart_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    plotOutput(ns("chart"))
  )
}

mod_chart_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    output$chart <- renderPlot(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_point())
    
  })
}


# Module for table --------------------------------------------------------

mod_table_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        mod_filter_ui(ns("filter_chart"))),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput(ns("table"))
      )
    )
  )
}

mod_table_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    filt_mtcars <- mod_filter_server("filter_chart")
    
    output$table <- renderTable(filt_mtcars())
    
  })
}


# Module for filter -------------------------------------------------------

mod_filter_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("cyl_filt"),
                label = "Filter for # of Cylinders",
                choices = NULL)
  )
}

mod_filter_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    updateSelectInput("cyl_filt",
                      session = session,
                      choices = unique(mtcars$cyl),
                      selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)[1])
    
    filt_mtcars <- reactive(mtcars |> filter(cyl == input$cyl_filt))
    
    return(filt_mtcars)

  })
}



# Cicerone ----------------------------------------------------------------

guide <- Cicerone$
  new()$
  step(el = "mainTabs",
       "Main Tabs",
       "These are the main tabs set in the main server")$
  step(el = "tab1-subTabs",
       "Sub Tabs",
       "These are the subtabs under Tab1")$
  step(el = "tab1-chart_1-chart",
       "Chart",
       "This is a chart!")$
  step(el = "tab1-table_1-table",
       "Table",
       "This is a table!",
       tab = "Table",
       tab_id = "tab1-subTabs")$
  step(el = ".form-group.shiny-input-container",
       "Filters",
       "Here you can filter the table by number of cylinders.")


# Main app ----------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  use_cicerone(),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id = "mainTabs",
                tabPanel("tab1", mod_subtabs_ui("tab1")),
                tabPanel("tab2", mod_subtabs_ui("tab2"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  guide$init()$start()
  
  mod_subtabs_server("tab1")
  outputOptions(output, "tab1-table_1-table", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  mod_subtabs_server("tab2")
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Thank you, this is very helpful.  I have both this example and my full app working but ONLY if I stay on tab1.  If I change the second to last step to el = "tab2-table_1-table" and tab_id = "tab2-subTabs", it does not work.  I did also add outputOptions(output, "tab2-table_1-table", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

You are right, this does not work. I will have a deeper look inside why the transition does not work.

As an intermediate result at least a workaround: What seems to make the transition on the "upper" tab work is if you insert an intermediate step before you go to the table as you describe, e.g. step(el = "tab2-subTabs", "Tab2", "These are the subTabs of tab2!", tab = "tab2", tab_id = "mainTabs")$. But then the last step to the filters will not work, what I can circumvent by supplying an id. I think that a general problem here might be the missing ids, e.g. tab = "Table" could be a problem ... However, I have to take a deeper look into the underlying js later ...
